# Replace certain content in txt file and save it using PHP?

Tags: php, str-replace

So I receive variable replace it in certain area in txt file and save it back. I get page number and according to it I get exploded data. Anyway I'll post a code below to make it more clear:

```
$pgnm = $_GET['page']; //This is the page number as I've said.

$conts = file_get_contents("content.txt");
```

the content of content.txt looks like this:

```
text1|text2|text3
```

I display this content in certain pages. For example on first page: text1, on second text2, etc.

Now i'm working on a form where I successfully change these. I get as I've said page number and text:

```
$text = "new text"; //this is the content which I want to be replaced instead of text2.
```

I make the content.txt file look like this after its saved: text1|new text|text2

So lets go on:

```
$exp = explode("|", $conts); //this explodes data into slashes. 

$rep = str_replace($exp[$pgnm], $text, $conts);

file_put_contents("content.txt", $rep); // Saving file
```

All these above-mentioned operations work perfectly, but here's my problem now. This only works if content.txt has certain content, if it's empty it enters my new text and that's all: 'new text' and that's all. Maybe I want to add second page content 'new text2' and after I finish entering it and save I want the file to be displayed like this: new text|new text2. If the content of content.txt looks like this: 'new text|' str_replace doesn't replace empty string. So that's my another problem too.

I tried everything, but couldn't manage to anything about this two problems. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: why not use database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use your `$exp` array for building the content. I mean `$exp` contains all the blocks as an `array()` one by one. So you just change, or add new values to the array (no `str_replace()` needed). Then rebuild using `implode('|',$exp);`.

As for your code;

```
$exp = explode("|", $conts); //this explodes data into slashes. 
$exp[$pgnm] = $text;
file_put_contents("content.txt", implode('|',$exp)); // Saving file
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of str_replace use this code:

```
$pgnm       = 1;
$text       = 'new text';
$conts      = 'text1||text3';
$exp        = explode('|', $conts); 
$exp[$pgnm] = $text;
$rep        = implode('|', $exp);
var_dump($rep); // string(20) "text1|new text|text3"
```

Comment: it returns: string(0) ""